# Is user defined automatic completion possible in PuTTY?

Tags: putty, autocomplete

I have often to enter the same strings in PuTTy. Is there a way to teach PuTTY to auto replace a short string with its long version, e.g. to convert "pcname" into "pcname.very-long-domain-name.de"?

Comment: I would think that's a function of the computer you're connecting to in putty, not putty itself. Alternatively, this might be a job for a program like AutoHotKey, if you want to handle this before you're actually connected to a remote system.

Comment: I see, I try to put the cart before the horse. I have to solve the problem for Terminal on server side. Thank You!